# Different types of publications

Tags: publications

During the literature review for my Master thesis, I have got in touch with many different types of scientific publications, meaning **papers**, **working papers**, **conference papers**, **seminar papers** and so on.

I have seen many discussion about sub-categories of these main objects but never one being at this higher level of grouping.

Thus, I was wondering which are the main difference among them in order to do some kind of hierarchy of content reliability when I read them. And clearly if there exist other types, please add them so we can build a complete collection.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe there is a consistent hierarchy to find at that level?

Comment: In which field?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Computer Science

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist a lot of standards for document/publication types. Here are some examples:

- [ORCiD work types](http://members.orcid.org/api/resources/work-types)
- [Endnote reference types](http://endnote.com/sites/en/files/m/pdf/en-x7-win-editing-reference-types-styles.pdf)
- [RAK WB](http://files.dnb.de/pdf/rak_wb_netz.pdf), see chapter 1.2 (a system created for German libraries with a hierarchy for document types)
- [DRIVER used by DINI](https://wiki.surfnet.nl/display/DRIVERguidelines/Publication+type+vocabulary) (repositories)
- ...

As stated [here](http://www.abc-clio.com/ODLIS/odlis_p.aspx#pubtype), each database might have its own definition, i.e. there are a lot of standards. Before creating a new one, I'd check if one of the already existing standards fits your requirements.

Note: Please feel free to edit this question to add more standards for document/publication types.